# SELECT STUFF rewrite to Redshift

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-redshift

I have a SQL script, that I need to convert to redshift.

Here is the part, where I have a problem:

```
LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT STUFF((
                SELECT ','+ clo.name
                FROM    public.label_entities cl
                JOIN    public.label_history clo
                ON      clo.id = cl.labelid
                WHERE   clo.parentid = 993
                        AND cl.entityid = clv.contactid
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ) ,1,1,'') AS Services
        ) AS labelServices
```

I have read that I can use `SELECT LISTAGG` and try to use it like this:

```
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT LISTAGG((
            SELECT ','+ clo.name
            FROM    public.label_entities cl
            JOIN    public.label_history clo
            ON      clo.id = cl.labelid
            WHERE   clo.parentid = 993
                    AND cl.entityid = clv.contactid
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ) ,1,1,'') AS Services
    ) AS labelServices
```

But it does not work.

So how I can rewrite it to be correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need all the XML stuff. In fact, it is XML that is doing the aggregation in SQL Server, not `STUFF()`.  `STUFF()` is just used for beautifying the string after it is created.

So, something like this:

```
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT cl.entityid, LISTAGG(clo.name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY clo.name) as names
 FROM public.label_entities cl JOIN
      public.label_history clo
      ON clo.id = cl.labelid
 WHERE clo.parentid = 993
 GROUP BY cl.entityid
) AS labelServices
ON labelServices.entityid = clv.contactid
```

Comment: `Invalid operation: column "cl.entityid" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function;`


got his error

Comment: @EugeneSukh add `GROUP BY entityid` as the error says. Be careful though. Redshift is a *columnstore* database which means per-column aggregates, groupings are insanely fast but per-row access can be slow. `STRING_AGG` in SQL Server and `LISTAGG` in Redshift do need to find individual rows and extract values. A well-designed star schema could be orders of magnitude faster than something that requires multiple joins, string aggregations etc.

Comment: Thank's so much@PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 0):

use `replace()` instead of `stuff()`

```
select STUFF(', hai, hello, fine', 1, 1, '')
select replace(','+', hai, hello, fine', ',,', '')  --- ', hai, hello, fine' would be
                                                    --- returned by inner select
```

**EDIT 1**

```
select REPLACE(','+ 
 (
  SELECT ','+ clo.name
  FROM    public.label_entities cl
  JOIN    public.label_history clo
  ON      clo.id = cl.labelid
  WHERE   clo.parentid = 993
  AND cl.entityid = clv.contactid
  FOR XML PATH('')
 )
 ,',,'
 ,''
)
```